# Kendo Window won't load data from model

Tags: user-interface, view, kendo-ui, window, loading

```
@model Example.Model1ViewModel

@if (Model != null && Model.TableSix != null)
{
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:60%"></td>
            <td style="width:20%">Outstanding Amount</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td class="Total cursor">@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.TableSix.Total)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.TableSix.One)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.TableSix.Two)</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
}

<div style="display: none">
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
 .Name("RemainingAssetsDrillDown")
 .Modal(true)
 .Title("Item Drill Down")
 .Actions(actions => actions.Close())
 .Content(@<text>
      <div>
        <table>
         <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.TableSix.One)</td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </text>)
</div>
```

)
    
    $(".Total").click(function () {
    $("#MVC").load('@Url.Action("PartList", "Report")');
    var win = $("#DrillDown").data("kendoWindow");
    win.center().open();
     });

```
<style type="text/css">
.cursor {
cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

So, the problem is that @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.TableSix.One) fetches the correct value from the view model in the first table, but in the table under kendo window I get the value as 0.

Any idea how I can get @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.TableSix.One) to display the value from the view model into the table that is under kendo window?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: After adding the missing </table> on the non-window table and the closing bracket for the Kendo().Window() and adding a .Total button to click, this works for me: the window table displays the same value from my mock Model for One as the non-window table.  Double-check everything.

Comment: Hi The Dead Pirate Stephen. first of all, my apologies! I was in such a rush while posting this, sorry! Also, I believe that I have everything written correct at least syntactically and hence the project is running and can deliver an output, but certainly not the one I desire. I have made the corrections in the post could you  please tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: For your clarification I will post the output:

Output:
                    Outstanding Amount
Total             500
One              200
Two              300. This is what the non-window table looks like. Where as the windowed table looks as follows:

One              0 (Here is the problem, I expect the 0 to be 200 same as in the non windowed table). Hopefully this brings some clarification to the question.

Also, I am really sorry if this post is getting messy, but this is my first post and I'm still learning :) Thanks!